# Why did I get access to the wallet?

Tags: account, wallet, phantom-wallet

I generated a 12-word BIP39 word sequence using a third-party library (not from the solana tools).
Next, I went to the phantom mobile application and added a wallet by restoring it using a 12-word seed phrase.

Address: 8Y2XdtmZg6YRiYrzZxgpNw8yUg3JUJ7pUar5qbGjUiFf

My question is, why did I get access to the wallet? Does the wallet address initially exist on the blockchain and does the bip39 algorithm generate a unique passphrase to access this wallet address?

*I apologize in advance for possibly very stupid questions and would appreciate any information.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wallet algorithms work that way, that from a given seed phrase they always create the same set of addresses (accounts) where you store cryptocurrency or tokens. At the same time, the wallet will also create access keys to each individual address (the private keys) and protect them inside. It always creates the same set of addresses and private keys from one seed phrase. So if you will set up another wallet with the same seed phrase, it will create an identical copy of the first one. This is called a deterministic wallet, and almost all modern wallets work this way.

https://getcoinplate.com/blog/is-a-seed-phrase-the-same-as-a-private-key-the-ultimate-guide-to-private-keys-and-recovery-seed-phrases/

Comment: yes, but I didn’t create a wallet anywhere before generating the seed phrase. I generated it using the bip39 library. Then I opened the phantom app, entered the seed phrase and got access to the wallet. It turns out that I got access to an already existing address, and did not create a new one. It turns out by generating a seed phrase, you can access an already existing address(not created by me) that corresponds to the received seed phrase ?

Comment: Yeah, you can generate a seed phrase and a new account with the seed phrase. But it is almost impossible to get an already existing address.